# unexpected matlab expression very simple code.

Tags: matlab, expression

There seems to be a small problem with my matlabcode.
i'm trying to calculate Qx using this simple formula.
Anybody has an idea what i'm doing wrong?

```
Error: File: functie5612.m Line: 2 Column: 28
Unexpected MATLAB expression.

Error in oef5612 (line 2)
Qx=functie5612(D)
```

Define my function

```
function Qx=functie5612(D)
Qx= D*(11-(0.1*D)/(0.28-D))0.8
end
```

Initial parameter

```
D=[0;2;4;6;8;10;12;14;16;18;20;22;23;24;25;26;27;28;30;32;34;36;38]
```

Using my function

```
Qx=functie5612(D)
```

making a graph

```
clf
figure(1);
plot(D,Qx);
title ('Optimale dilutiesnelheid','FontSize',12);
xlabel('D(1/h)','FontSize',12);
ylabel('Volumetrische biomassaproductiviteit(kg/(m^3*h)','FontSize',12);
legend('Substraat','Product','Biomassa') `
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the explicit `*` when doing multiplication. That is, you should have `)*0.8` and not just `)0.8`.
So your function should look like:

```
function Qx=functie5612(D)
Qx= D*(11-(0.1*D)/(0.28-D))*0.8
end
```

However, this is still incorrect (dimensions mismatch). If you are looking at elementwise multiplication of `D`, you will need to use the `.` operator. The code would look like:

```
Qx= D.*(11-(0.1*D)./(0.28-D))*0.8
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you get is due to a matrix dimesion mismatch.
So, you need to use the .* operator instead of *

```
Qx= D.*(11-(0.1.*D)./(0.28-D)).*0.8;
```

Comment: That would give you a "inner matrix dimensions must agree" error

Comment: you're wrong, I tested it. It returns me a `23*1` vector.

Comment: Sorry, my original comment was unclear. Your code works. However, the error in the original question is not generated by dimension mismatches.